# How to generate multiple ethereum addresses using HDWallet?

Tags: addresses, hd-wallets

```js
    const mnemonic= 'clown shiver beach wheel this mixture emotion illness fatigue amateur talent bitter'
    console.log(`0x${hdwallet.derive(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`).getAddress().toString('hex')}`) 

    const seed =   Buffer.from('408fb4ad29e82ae696c857795fa94c0aad444578effa428ddd1b969b35f96f298911c9b066a6dda3cc47ed85d903be61b67fe97895a8bc68d1a20ce014b7ae80', 'hex')

    const hdwallet= HDWallet.fromSeed(seed)
    console.log(`0x${hdwallet.derive(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`).getAddress().toString('hex')}`)
    var pubkey=hdwallet.derive(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`).getPublicKey().toString('hex');
    var privateKey=hdwallet.derive(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`).getPrivateKey().toString('hex');
    var address=`0x${hdwallet.derive(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`).getAddress().toString('hex')}`;
    console.log(pubkey)   
    console.log(privateKey)
    console.log(address)
```

What am I missing?
How to iterate derivation path to get new address every time?

Answer (score 1):

Derivation path follows this convention:

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

So you can increase `address_index` from 0 to get new addresses from same mnemonic.

For more details: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki

Comment: yeah i know that but i don't want to do that manually every time

Comment: i want to itearate index on every request by it self
i am stuck in that

Comment: That sounds like a good use for a backend database :-)
Each time you call this routine, do an atomic table update to get the next index. 
Your index can have really large numbers so it should keep working for a long time.